# Multipart request with retrofit 2.0 Android why can't I see multipart inside?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I try to make a multipart request with retrofit 2.0 to upload an image to my server.

For now I have RequestBody with my image byte[]

```
RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), lastImageBytes);
```

Then I create from data in this way

```
MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upfile", DeviceUtils.Companion.getTimeStamp() + ".png", requestFile);
```

My retrofit interface

```
@Headers({
   "Accept: */*",
   "Content-type: multipart/form-data"
})
@POST("upload")
@Multipart
Call<Void> uploadImage(@Part("idn") RequestBody idn, @Part MultipartBody.Part image);
```

Request is sent but I cannot see the multipart inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove this line `“Content-type: multipart/form-data”` inside your `@Headers` and `retrofit` will add correct header automatically with multipart boundry.